# Any better way to handle the services URL different between environment?

Tags: dart

Any better way to handle the services URL different between environment?

The service URL address is https://localhost:8080/v1/api-url
But my production environment is https://localhost:28080/v1/api-url

Before I build my dart code, I always need to change URL address to  https://localhost:28080.

```
static final String URL = "https://localhost:8080";
HttpRequest.request(URL + /v1/api-url, method: 'GET');
```

So,  I want to know any better way to handle this on pub build?

Answer (score 0):

Does your installation support relative URLs?  If so, use /v1/api-url and do not include the https://localhost:???? at all.

Comment: My problem is when I run in Dartium, the url is not localhost:8080 but localhost:<random> port. Therefore in my Dart code, I need to change the URL to localhost:8080.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of what your set up is? How are you running Dartium? Sounds like you are launching from an IDE that is running pub serve on a random port. What is running on port 8080?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the current URL from the browser and align the URL for your request:

```
import 'dart:html' show window;
void main() {
 print(window.location);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could externalize that configuration, then use a different configuration file for deployment.  This package might help:

https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dart_config